How can I fill the gaps on the Shopify collection page when I hide or exclude products?
The first page is not filled entirely, but it already created other pages after excluding/hidding particular taged products.
{% for product in collection.products %}
  {% if product.tags contains 'hideProd' %}{% continue %}{% endif %}
  <!-- your product grid item -->
{% endfor %}

Gaps should fill.
For example, if there are 100 products in a collection and the pagination is set to 5 pages (with 20 products per page), but 20 products are excluded or hidden, the pagination should adjust to display only 4 pages.

You can first remove all those products from the list that needs to be hidden and after that loop over the products to display them, instead of removing the products inside the loop.

It's far easier to create another collection and use it inside the loop. Pagination is very tricky
